# looker studio pivot chart dataset configuration error

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio, google-community-connector

I try to develop looker connector to my db. And now i test it with creating report and all worked perfectly until
when i try to use pivot chart with two metrics with connection. One of this is calculated from schema fields memory_per_query = sum(memory_usage_mb) / sum(query_count). Second is plain query_count

Ive checked all queries that goes to looker conector script - they all the same and no errors
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPnZG.png)
I've got next error text:
Looker Studio cannot connect to your data set.
Failed to fetch data from the underlying data set
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUmHw.png)

But when i put additional in chart metric field query_count one more time it begin work properly way
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWU0g.png)

In plain table chart there is no such problem
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJMRL.png)